# Passing a variable to another webpage using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to pass a variable from one page to another using JavaScript so that the following works:

```
main.html:

<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<p>Links to worksheets: &nbsp
<a href="worksheets.html" >1 &nbsp
<a href="worksheets.html">2 &nbsp
<a href="worksheets.html">3 &nbsp

</body>
</html>


worksheets.html:

<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<p id="mainParagraph"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("mainParagraph").innerHTML = "This is worksheet number " + localStorage.getItem("worksheetNumber");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

What I am needing is a way for the main file to pass the worksheet number to local storage.  I would like to do this without having a separate JavaScript method for each worksheet, as I intend to have hundreds of worksheets.  Another option may be to have an inline JavaScript method for each link, but I can't get anything to work.

Can anyone suggest a way to pass the worksheet number when the link is clicked?  Local storage seems to be a good way to do it, but I'm open to other ways of doing it with JavaScript.

Thank you.

Comment: The previous page will be navigated away from in your application, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Ideally I'd like it to be domain.com/1/ and domain.com/2/ as the worksheet pages, but I know that would get complex, or require me to store hundreds of similar pages.  And I don't need people to bookmark the numbered pages, only the main page.

Comment: "What I am needing is a way for the main file to pass the worksheet number to local storage. I would like to do this without having a separate JavaScript method for each worksheet" --- I don't quite understand why it would require a separate JS method for each worksheet? Could the worksheet number not be read from a shared method? Or passed as an argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a URL parameter to pass along the worksheet number:

```
main.html:

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Links to worksheets: &nbsp
  <a href="worksheets.html?num=1">1 &nbsp
  <a href="worksheets.html?num=2">2 &nbsp
  <a href="worksheets.html?num=3">3 &nbsp
</body>
</html>


worksheets.html:

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="mainParagraph"></p>
  <script>
  let worksheetNumber = location.search.replace(/^.*\bnum=([0-9]+).*$/, '$1');
  document.getElementById("mainParagraph").innerHTML = "This is worksheet number " + worksheetNumber;
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Alternatively, you can set a local storage item with the number in your main page using JavaScript, then read that in your worksheet.

Yet another solution is to set and read a cookie.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I'm after.  I don't really want cookies as I'm trying to keep it simple, and don't want to have to ask for permission or anything.